# Update query adding values from multi column case statement in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite, update-query

I am looking to calculate a single value from four columns using a CASE WHEN statement for each of four columns. For example, column a,b,c,d have numeric values and I want to classify them and sum the total between each of the four columns.

```
 UPDATE table SET total = CASE 
  WHEN a = 0 THEN 0
  WHEN a BETWEEN  1 AND 25 THEN 1
  WHEN a BETWEEN 26 AND 50 THEN 2
  WHEN a BETWEEN 51 AND 75 THEN 3
  ELSE 4
 END
```

My end goal is to do this for each column (a,b,c,d) and sum the results across the four columns in a single SQL statement.

My idea is to do a CASE WHEN for column a + CASE WHEN for column b + CASE WHEN for column c + CASE WHEN for column d. I am not sure how to structure a query for SpatiaLite to do this.

Is this the correct approach?